# Condition check help xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

In viewDidLoad I show a text on label

```
[label setText:@"hello"];
```

and after a certain event I hide it. Now I want a condition to check

```
if([label.text isEqualToString:@"hello"] is visible on screen for >= 30 seconds)
{
//some code......
}
```

Please help me to make this check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
    {
     //your method.
     [label setText:@"hello"];
     [self performSelector:@selector(afterDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:30];
    }

   -(void)afterDelay {
    [label setText:@""];
    }
```

And the condition that you can use:

```
   if(label.text.length == 0) {
   }
```

Comment: though not exactly what i wanted but got a hint from your answer..than ks:)

Answer (score 0):

To find out when your text has been on the screen for 30 seconds you will need to use a timer. The timer class for IOs is the `NSTimer`. Check the [Apple Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003747) for more information about it.

You will probably want to use the `scheduleTimerWithInterval:target:selector:repeats` method and set it to be non-repeating and the time interval to 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   if ([label.text isEqualToString:@"hello"]) {
            NSTimer * tm = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(hideLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }

    -(void)hideLabel {
          self.label.hidden = YES;
    }
```